# Return with last id laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, return, submit

I have a form, with two submit buttons first button is submit and return to a page, and the second button is to submit and return to the same form, what I want to do is when you stay at the same form that 2 fields remain filled with the data that has been submitted, but I tried different ways and it didn't work. This is my controller

```
$retour->ordernumber =  request('ordernumber');
$retour->customername = request('customername');

$retour->save();

        if ($request->submit === 'submit') {
            return redirect('/return')->with('message', 'Approved');

        } else {
            return redirect('/return/create')->with('message', 'Approved, you can make a new report.');
        }
```

And the fields I want remain filled are the ordernumber and customername

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Ordernumber</label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text">653</span>
</div>
<input type="text" name="ordernumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ordernumber" value="{{ old('ordernumber') }}">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Customername</label>
<input type="text" name="customername" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter customername" value="{{ old('customername') }}">
</div>
```

Comment: `$retour->id` doesn't work?

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by using session.

in controller

```php
use Session;               // at the top
$retour->ordernumber =  request('ordernumber');
$retour->customername = request('customername');
$retour->save();

Session::put('ordernumber',request('ordernumber'));
Session::put('customername',request('customername'));
Session::save();
```

in view

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Ordernumber</label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <span class="input-group-text">653</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="ordernumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ordernumber" value="{{ Session::get('ordernumber') }}">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Customername</label>
   <input type="text" name="customername" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter customername" value="{{ Session::get('customername') }}">
</div>
```

If you want to use old() helper then you need to rediect with ->withInput();

```php
return redirect('/return')->with('message', 'Approved')->withInput();
```